# Can I use the L-BFGS optimizer in Spark through pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I would like to create my own estimator in python in PySpark.
I would like to use the L-BFGS optimization algorithm to fit or any other optimization algorithm available.
How can I access these optimization algorithms through pyspark? 
Is there an example that shows how this is done?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I was able to do this in scala using the breeze numerical processing library, but not sure how do it in python.

Comment: I was not able to figure this out in python.

Answer (score 0):

`from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.html#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS